# Is there anyone used the denclue algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have downloaded the source code from http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~hawks/faculdade/data_mining/denclue_doxygen_19122006/main.html,
but it does not work for me, my clustering dataset's form is like this
54621,43523
52694,42750
53253,43024
54925,42624
54973,43980
52967,42955

but when I run the commend `./denclue -d 2 -s 10 -x 0.1 -i a1_part.txt -o output_file`.It gives the segmentation fault. when I change the `-d 2` to `-d 20` or higher, it works, but it's wrong.Ha

Comment: Have you tried debugging he segmentation fault? Is your input format the right format? Many apps seem to expect Gnuplot-style data, probably because the authors also used Gnuplot for visualization (and `,` is the decimal separator in some locales).